# How to Get Gnuplot to Read Input File with Hex Data

Tags: gnuplot

I'm collecting data from a CAN bus viewer that saves it as a text file in a fixed column format, like this:

```
  4681)     24123.0  Rx         0488  8  79 00 DF 58 66 00 FF 00
```

I'd like to have gnuplot create a plot using column 2 for 'x' and the sum of columns 10 and 11 as the 'y' value, where column 10 is the LSB and column 11 is the MSB (so it needs to be multiplied by 256 first). Both columns 10 and 11 are in hexadecimal. The documentation I've read implies that a sprintf format can be used, but I'm not having any luck getting the correct syntax.

Comment: I guess you must use an external tool to do the conversion. In general one can use a format after the `using` statement like `plot 'data.dat' using 1:2 '%lf%lf'. Unfortunately, this format supports only `%lf` an no other (hexadecimal) specifiers.

Comment: @Christoph And that's what I ended up doing. I wrote a short Python script to read the trace data file, do the conversions I needed, and create a new file with just the `x` and `y` data. And then it was just `plot 'data.dat' using 1:2`.

Comment: Ok. You could also do this on-the-fly without intermediate file. If your python script reads from `sys.stdin` and writes to `sys.stdout` you could do `plot '< python myscript.py < data.dat' using 1:2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood that you have a *text* not *binary* file with hexadecimal numbers, this would be my suggestion. No need for external scripts, all can be done with gnuplot 4.6.0 (version at the time of OP's question). A few more data lines are added as well as labels on the plot to check the test result.

**Data:** `SO24727223.dat`

```
4681)     24123.0  Rx         0488  8  79 00 DF 58 66 00 FF 00
4681)     24124.0  Rx         0488  8  79 00 DF 58 00 01 FF 00
4681)     24125.0  Rx         0488  8  79 00 DF 58 01 02 FF 00
4681)     24126.0  Rx         0488  8  79 00 DF 58 FF 01 FF 00
```

**Code:** (works with gnuplot>=4.6.0)

```
### construct/plot hex numbers
reset

FILE = "SO24727223.dat"

HexToInt(col1,col2) = int("0x".strcol(col1).strcol(col2))
myLabel(col1,col2)  = sprintf("0x%s%s\n=%d",strcol(col1),strcol(col2),HexToInt(col1,col2))

set key noautotitle
set offsets 0.5,0.5,50,50

plot FILE u 2:(HexToInt(11,10)) w lp pt 7, \
       '' u 2:(HexToInt(11,10)):(myLabel(11,10)) w labels offset 1,-1
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]